# use AWK to divide the values in a CSV file by a certain number

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a CSV file (100 columns) like this

```
  10,20,30,40,50,...,1000
  20,30,40,50,60,...,1010
  .
  .
  .
```

and I want to divide all the values by 10, so that I will get

```
  1,2,3,4,5,...,100
  2,3,4,5,6,...,101
  .
  .
  .
```

How can I do this with AWK? Thank you very much!

Comment: You chose some bad examples then, from you comment about "real calculation" If you have 13, you'll get 1.3. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Sorry for the bad example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i/=10;}1' infile
```